# Stored procedure usage with example

Tags: c#, sql

How to use stored procedure instead of query in connection string. Can u suggest me coding???

Comment: *instead of query in connection string* I hope you know the connection string is for some other purpose rather than querying. Please take some time to formulate an actual question.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
string spName = "stored_proc_name";
string idParameterValue = "someId";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(spName, connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", idParameterValue));
        connection.Open();

        IDbDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = command;

        // (*) Put here a code block of the actual SP execution logic
        // There are different ways of SP execution and it depends on
        // return result set type, see below
    }
}
```

(*) Choose an appropriate approach:

1. Save output result set in a DataSet

   ```
   // Store output result set in the DataSet
   DataSet ds = ExecuteQuery(da);
   ```
2. OR read single integer as stored procedure return value (not OUT param!)

   ```
   IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
   if (reader != null && reader.Read())
   {
       retValue = (reader.GetInt32(returnParamName));
   }
   ```
3. In case when stored procedure does not return anything

   ```
   bool successfull = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1;
   ```

---

**Helper methods**

```
private static DataSet ExecuteQuery(IDataAdapter da)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("rawData");
    da.Fill(ds);

    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "row";
    foreach (DataColumn c in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        c.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
    }

    return ds;
}

public static class DataReaderExtensions
{  
    public static Int32 GetInt32(this IDataReader rdr, string fieldName)
    {
        int ordinal = rdr.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
        return !rdr.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? rdr.GetInt32(ordinal) : Int32.MinValue;
    }
}
```

Useful links:

- [CommandType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype.aspx)

Comment: no need to close the connection when it is wrapped in a `using`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your sql-commands - in this case a call of the stored procedure - and then connect to the database, send your query and receive the result.

Don't forget to close the connection afterwards!

A good tutorial is online on [csharp-station](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson07.aspx).

I can't describe the whole procedure here, if you have more detailed questions just come back and ask - that's what Stackoverflow is for :)